# aligning images and paragraphs in pairs in two colums without overlapping images (wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-float, margin

I have the WYSIWYG-editor from wordpress, where I put in text and images. However, I would like to pull the images to the left of the text (with a negative margin-left), so that I have a column with my text and aligned to the top of some paragraphs some images on a column on the left. 
My problem is, that when I have two paragraphs aligned with two images and the height of the first paragraph is less than the height of the according image, the 2nd image is overlapping with the first because the start of the 2nd paragraph is above the bottom of the first image. In this case I would like to push the 2nd image simply down, so it is placed below the first without any overlap.

What I want:

```css
.img {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -250px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-xs-offset-5">
      <p class="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.  </p>
      <p class="img"><img src="https://placehold.it/240x200/333333"/>
      <p class="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <strong>!!! The darker image is overlapped by the grey one. Both have the same height.</strong> </p>
      <p class="img"><img src="https://placehold.it/240x200"/>
      <p class="p3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help! I'm curious what your solution will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, could you not just add a clear?

```
.img {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -250px;
  clear:left;
}
```

Comment: That's it! Sometimes it's just that simple. Thank you!

Comment: @BennoMeyer - No problem - I like the easy ones :-)

Answer (score 0):

What  you need is called "clearfix". Add this to the .img css: `clear:both;`